# jQuery toggle dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, menu, submenu

Im making some dropdown menu with jQuery effect, now im need litle help for creating one more submenu (in dropdownmenu).

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Homepage</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sumbenu</a></li> // i want to add one more submenu, in this submenu
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul>li').stop().slideToggle(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked into jQuery UI? They have a "menu" that could make this really easy for you. http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An extremely simple example:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tjf22z6p/

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Homepage</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
}
#nav{
    left: 0;
}
li ul{
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideToggle(400);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry im newbie, but how i can make, the first submenu is direction from bottom not from left side, and the 2. submenu from the right side appears (like here: http://jqueryui.com/menu/ )